# Jest unit test issue when importing a Service from Shared Library in Angular

Tags: angular, ts-jest, angular-library, angular-unit-test

I have the following test suits

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { OrdersComponent } from './orders.component';


describe('OrdersComponent', () => {
  let component: OrdersComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<OrdersComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule, MatDialogModule, MatSnackBarModule],
      declarations: [OrdersComponent]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OrdersComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('Orders should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I'm importing CommonService from my Angular Library `my-lib` in my OrderComponent

```
...
import { CommonService } from 'my-lib/ui';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-orders',
  templateUrl: './orders.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./orders.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class OrdersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
```

I got the following error when running my test

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')

    > 16 | import { CommonService } from 'my-lib/ui';
         | ^

 at registerLocaleData (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:20319:25)
      at registerLocaleData (node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/common.mjs:2561:12)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/my-lib/fesm2022/my-lib-ui.mjs:291:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/pages/orders/orders.component.ts:16:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/pages/orders/orders.component.spec.ts:3:1)
```

Is there any configuration for Jest to add when using a shared library ? or maybe I've to mock this service ?

It seems to be an internal angular error, maybe I am not exporting the service from the lib in the right way ?!

Comment: Yes, unit tests should always mock external dependencies, otherwise you rather have an integration test than unit test.

Comment: The error still confuses me !

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm I am not calling the service, the problem occurs during the component initialization

Comment: It looks like the error lies in your `CommonService`, maybe in the constructor you call the registerLocaleData with invalid values

Comment: @bmtheo I don't think so, I'm not calling `registerLocaleData` anywhere. the project is built and running without any problem

Comment: Jest sometimes is confusing, but yes, maybe you need mock service, it seems like sometime toLowerCase is called, another thing is material modules, you need to check if you import all modules used in the OrdersComponent (check the module). 

Could you provide more details about this service and the module where the OrdersComponent is declared?

Comment: @smaillns ok no idea then, the method I would use to find out is try to make the minimal repro in another project (or on stackblitz) and see when the problem appears. For example I would remove all dependencies of CommonService to see if it changes anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I was able to provide for this issue, was by **mocking** the external services (as show bellow)

Note: I'm using `Jest`

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { OrdersComponent } from './orders.component';
import { CommonService } from 'my-lib/ui';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { OrdersFiltersComponent } from './filters/filters.component';
import { OrdersListComponent } from './list/list.component';

jest.mock('my-lib/ui', () => ({
  CommonService: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    setTitle: jest.fn(),
    setSubTitle: jest.fn(),
    showSearchBar: jest.fn(),
  }))
}));
describe('OrdersComponent', () => {
  let component: OrdersComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<OrdersComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      declarations: [OrdersComponent],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: CommonService,
          useValue: {
            setTitle: jest.fn(),
            setSubTitle: jest.fn(),
            showSearchBar: jest.fn(),
          },
        }
      ],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OrdersComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('Orders should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```